引数が string enum か文字列かによって処理を変えたい
Typescript（使っているのは Version 5.7.2 です） で，ある string enum Foo を定義しておいて， Foo | string を受け取る関数で，引数がどちらかによって処理を変えたいです．たとえば
enum Foo {
    A = "Good",
    B = "Fair",
    C = "Common",
}

// Foo を， enum string で紐づけられたのではない文字列に変換する
function fooToString(f: Foo) : string | undefined{
    switch(f){
        case Foo.A:
            return "A!!";
        case Foo.B:
            return "B";
        case Foo.C:
            return "C...";
        // 入れざるを得ない？
        default:
            return undefined;
    }
}

// s が文字列ならそのまま，Foo ならちょっと別のことをして返す…ということをしたい気持ち
function bar(s: string | Foo): string {
    if (typeof s === "string") {
        return s;
    } else {
        return fooToString(s)!;
    }
}

なのですが，tsc は型エラーを検出してくれるものの，typeof Foo.A は結局 string になってしまう (javascript 的には "Good" と等価ということでしょうか？）ようで，以下のように上手くいきません．
// console.log(fooToString("a string")); ちゃんとコンパイラが弾いてくれる
console.log(fooToString(Foo.C)); // ちゃんと動く：C...
console.log(bar("a string")); // "a string"
console.log(bar(Foo.A)); // "Good" が帰ってくるけど，"A!!" であってほしい
console.log(typeof(Foo.A)); // string

どのようにすれば bar のような挙動をする関数を実現できるでしょうか？
コメントを頂いたのに関して追記: こういうことでしょうか，型を明示的に与えて変数にバインドしても挙動は変化しません．
const fooVal: Foo = Foo.A; // 型を与えておく
console.log(typeof(fooVal)); // string
console.log(bar(fooVal)); // "Good"


パラメータの渡し方の問題かも？ bar(Foo.A)ではなく、letやvarで何かの変数を定義してenumの値を設定し、それをパラメータに指定すれば良いのでは？

不可能だと思います。参考: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63754079

実行時にTypeScriptの型を判定することはできないので、Fooの値を列挙して比較することで判別する方法で妥協するのがよいかと思います。
function isFoo(value: string): value is Foo {
    return Object.values(Foo).includes(value as Foo);
}

function bar(s: string | Foo): string {
    if (isFoo(s)) {
        return fooToString(s)!; // `!`はfooToStringが必ず値を返すことを明示
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}


ありがとうございます！　(1) これは，この例では例えば "Good" という文字列と Foo.A は区別できない（それでやむを得ない），という理解でよいですか？ (2) イメージとして，Object.values(Foo).includes(v as Foo) という書き方はどの程度よくあるものでしょうか，つまり，変な設計のためにすごく特殊な・不格好な書き方をすることになっているのか，わりと許容される範囲のコードなのかが気になっています．

特殊で不格好とは思いませんが、参考までにこちらの英語版での質問/回答も載せておきます。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753808/how-to-check-the-type-is-enum-or-not-in-typescript

@Yosh (1)YESです。そこが「妥協」ですね。 (2)個人的には特に特殊or不格好とは思わないですが、仮にそう思う人がいたとしてもそれがisFoo()でラップされていることで全体的には許容範囲内に収まるかなあと思ったり。
